# Ability to highlight a specific range of an axis (plot bands)

Tags: recharts

I'm interested in showing standard deviations on a scatter plot. The visualization should make it easy to identify items that fall outside of the normal range. The normal range, centered around the mean, will extend until one standard deviation. The range from 2-3 standard deviations will be shown as a bands of a different color.

Is it possible to plot bands that highlight a specific range of an axis in recharts?

Similar features in different libraries:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/charts/chart/elements/plot-bands/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.